# Advantage of DyaActionForm over ActionForm?

Tags: struts

with the use DyaActionForm , we can define the form properties in strus-config.xml instead of creating new form bean class.The only advantage i can think is
it will provide is the properties defined in xml file there will be no need of compilation and reduce the development time. Is it the only main pupose of
dynaAction Form?

Answer (score 0):

It helps keep your code base slim. Less to test, less to break, etc.